# Can't check if dialog is showing

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

So a dialog is opened every time a text is received. I want it to not open one if there is one already open. I was trying to check if one was open by using isShowing() but I keep getting the method isShowing() is undefinded for the type AlertDialog.Builder. Here is the section of bad code. Any help would be so sweet right about now.

```
public class PopUpReply extends Activity{
AlertDialog.Builder alertbox;
AlertDialog.Builder alert;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // prepare the alert box
    alertbox.isShowing();
    alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Comment: There is something strange with this code. You call isShowing() and after that you initialize the dialog. You should get NullPointerException in this case.

Comment: You are correct. Completely rewriting. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no isShowing() method on the `AlertDialog.Builder` class.  There is one on the `Dialog` class though.

[AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html)

[Dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#isShowing%28%29)

An `AlertDialog.Builder` is used to create an `AlertDialog`.  Once you have an instance of an `AlertDialog`, you can determine whether or not it is still showing by then calling isShowing() on it.

Comment: ahh... Just changed it so the builder creates the dialog, then the dialog is shown. Before the builder was just shown. Testing... Will accept this if all goes smooth.

Comment: actually... Decided the best way to go is to see if the activity is already running, and just ignore the receiver if it already is.