# AlertDialog.cancel() and AlertDialog.dismiss() crash app

Tags: android

If I have

```
private AlertDialog somePrompt;
```

and later I call

```
somePrompt.dismiss();
```

or

```
somePrompt.cancel();
```

this will crash the app if the dialog was not previously shown like `somePrompt.show()`. I need to make sure that this dialog is cancelled or dismissed, so how do I check if it is shown/visible?

Comment: please refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498670/cant-check-if-dialog-is-showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your app is crashing because you aren't initializing your `AlertDialog` in these cases since you aren't calling `show()` on them. You probably only initialize them just before calling `show(). You need to check if they are`null` before calling these closing methods on them.

```
if (somePrompt != null)
{
    somePrompt.dismiss();
}
```

If this doesn't help then please post your logcat from the crash.

Also, if you need to see if it is shown before calling it then you can add an [isShowing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#isShowing%28%29) check

```
if (somePrompt != null && somePrompt.isShowing())
{
    somePrompt.dismiss();
}
```